# konvajs - set background color for a layer

Tags: layer, konvajs

How can I set the background color of a layer using Konva library?

I tried:

> ```
> dashLayerA1.setAttr("fill", 'black');
> ```

but it does not seem to do the trick.

Only by-pass I found was to create a shape rect and assign a color to it, but not convenient for what I want to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the layer's background directly.

Creating a rectangle for the background is a valid solution, that I used by myself.

If you **don't need to export** that background, you can just style stage container with CSS:

```js
stage.getContainer().style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

For more info take a look here: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Canvas_Background.html

Comment: It was supposed to work when I tried to export jpeg file with white background by setting   backgroundColor to 'white' but when I tried to do that, the stage still export jpeg file with black background though.

Comment: @WisarutBholsithi read the line in the answer. It has this `But it has one drawback. The CSS background will be not visible on export when you use methods like stage.toImage() and stage.toDataURL()`

Comment: I got it. Going to access into canvas in the stage variable to set background to white since the CSS background will not be visible on export since I DO use toDataURL for export a jpeg file.